# @Inject a Controller

Tags: dependency-injection, playframework, guice

We're actually trying to inject different Controller-Classes to implement a trimmed version and a full version.

we take a look on spring and guice and all the documentation is just about to inject variables like

```
@inject
static MyBean bean;
```

but is it possible to make the inject-declaration for a class like this

```
@Inject
public class MyRealBean implement MyBean
```

?

i think not, but perhaps... ;)
So the question is, where to put the inject-annotion for the controller in the play framework.
i figure out kind of a hack, but I'm not lucky with that.
i created a wrapper controller, who owns the bean-controller and send all message to it.

```
public Wrapper extends Controller {
@Inject
static MyBean bean;

public static void index() {
    bean.index();
}
```

perhaps somebody knows a better way or we're on the wrong way...

thanks

Comment: It's not obvious to me what you are trying to achieve, try to explain your problem with more descriptive examples.

Answer (score 2):

Put the `@Inject` annotation before constructor.

Comment: ok, we tried that and make a constructor bind in the AbstractModule implementation to bind the right class (see http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/ToConstructorBindings). and create the constructor `public MyRealBean(MyBean bean){};`. but now we get a IllegalStateException:Unable to create Guice injector error

Comment: are you creating a class that extends  AbstractModule and doing something like: Guice.createInjector(new YouModule()) somewhere?

Comment: @caarlos0 I do exactly something like this that you wrote.